# Getting NaN instead of number/value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

Should be simple syntax error but I don't know what it is

Controller:

```
    $scope.startCounter=3;

    $scope.startTimeouter = function (number) {  
      $scope.startCounter = number - 1;  
      mytimeouter = $timeout($scope.startTimeouter, 1000);  

      if($scope.startCounter<=0){
        $timeout.cancel(mytimeouter); 
        $scope.startTimeout();
      } 
        $scope.startTimerBtner=function(){
      $scope.startTimeouter();
    }


    $scope.stopTimerBtner = function () {  
        $timeout.cancel(mytimeouter);  
    } 
  }
```

HTML:

```
<a ng-click="startTimeouter(3);" >Click to Start Timer</a>
```

And the result is "3".."2"..."NaN"....any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing anything into `$scope.startTimeouter` in your `timeout`, so the value for `number` is undefined. Instead, set your function to:

```
$scope.startCounter=3;

$scope.startTimeouter = function (number) {
      $scope.startCounter = number - 1;  
      mytimeouter = $timeout(function(){$scope.startTimeouter($scope.startCounter)}, 1000);  

      if($scope.startCounter<=0){
        $timeout.cancel(mytimeouter); 
        $scope.startTimeout();
      } 
        $scope.startTimerBtner=function(){
      $scope.startTimeouter();
    }


    $scope.stopTimerBtner = function () {  
        $timeout.cancel(mytimeouter);  
    } 

}
```